# How to solve $\int_{-1}^1\int_1^3 u\cdot e^{uv} du\cdot dv$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

> Solve $\int_{-1}^1\int_1^3 u\cdot e^{uv} du\cdot dv$.

I don't think I'm getting this right:
$$
\int_{-1}^1\int_1^3 \frac{1}{2}u\cdot e^{uv} du\cdot dv=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1 \bigg(\bigg[u\frac{1}{v}e^{uv}-\frac{1}{v}e^{uv}\bigg]_1^3\bigg)dv=\\
=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1 \bigg(\bigg[\frac{3}{v}e^{3v}-\frac{1}{v}e^{3v}-\bigg(\frac{1}{v}e^{v}-\frac{1}{v}e^v\bigg)\bigg]\bigg)dv=\\
=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1 \bigg(\frac{3}{v}e^{3v}-\frac{1}{v}e^{3v}-0\bigg)dv=\\
=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1 \bigg(\frac{2}{v}e^{3v}\bigg)dv=\\
=\int_{-1}^1 \bigg(\frac{1}{v}e^{3v}\bigg)dv
 $$
At this point I'm stuck even with integration by parts.

The correct final answer is:
$$
\frac{(e^2-1)^2(e^2+1)}{2e^3}
$$

Comment: I would switch the order of integration, because the anti-derivative of $e^{uv}$ with respect to $v$ will allow you to cancel the factor of $u$.  Unfortunately, I'm too tired right now to check your work.

Comment: The correct result is $\dfrac{\left(e^2-1\right)^2 \left(1+e^2\right)}{e^3}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1\int_1^3 u\cdot e^{uv} du\cdot dv&=\int_1^3 \int_{-1}^1u\cdot e^{uv} dv\cdot du\\
&=\int_1^3 \left(e^u-e^{-u}\right) du\\
\end{align}